# Learn how to program/port through Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, programming, porting-ubuntu-touch

I am interested in learning how to program but except for some first tiny steps (like basics of Linux and HTML and getting CM running) I haven't acquired any skills and knowledge yet. However, I am planning on buying a new phone and/to run Ubuntu Touch on it. So I am wondering, if porting UT could be a **manageable** project to learn more about programming (porting)/phones/Ubuntu while getting me UT on a more preferred device and finally contributing to the Ubuntu community **or** is that a far too optimistic thought?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: You won't need to buy a new phone to learn programming. There is an emulator for both Ubuntu Touch and Android.

I own a nexus 4. Maybe that is the right device. You can flash Ubuntu Touch and also Android to it. It's also capable of dual-booting, although i did not try that. This way you can easily learn to port Android apps to UT.

Porting UT to an unsupported phone is IMHO too hard when learning to program. You should start small.